# Unwanted space between inline-block elements in IE8, appears related to parent height

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Having trouble removing the large space to the right of inline-block elements in IE8.

It seems related to the fact that the parent div has a height of 50%, as when I remove this style the layout works at the larger size.

Note the layout is fine in IE7 and IE9+. And as this same issue was occurring *before* I started using HTML5shiv to deal with the `<figure>` element I am ignoring this as a factor.

Hoping someone can help!

Here is the [test page](http://carolineelisa.com/test/maryloudesign/#profile) and a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The basic HTML:

```
<div class='gallery'>
    <div class='gallery-row'>
        <figure class='gallery-item'>
            <div class='gallery-icon '>
                <a class='fancybox' rel='fancybox-2' href=# >
                    <img width="267" height="400" src="xxx/wp-content/uploads/11-267x400.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </figure>
        <figure class='gallery-item'>
            <div class='gallery-icon '>
                <a class='fancybox' rel='fancybox-2' href=# >
                    <img width="665" height="400" src="xxx/wp-content/uploads/2-665x400.png" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.gallery {
    height:50%;
    line-height:0;
}
.gallery-item {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 10px 5px 0;
}
.gallery-item:last-child {
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
}
.gallery-row, .gallery-item, .gallery-icon  {
    height:100%;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Comment: I don't really know what's going on here, but here's a tip: When using   `inline-block` whitespace in your `html` can cause unwanted gaps, try and give your html a minified effect to see if that helps.

Comment: One option could rather than use `inline-block` you could use `display: block` and `float: left`

Comment: Thanks connor.js, but not sure what you mean by minified effect on the html? And thanks also Pattle but I have spent quite a bit of time working on this layout and I'd like o stick to `inline-block`.

Comment: The propertie `inline-block` adds 4px margin to the elements, here you have a list of tricks to avoid those spaces
http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Thanks ppollono but we are talking about more than 4px. I've added a screenshot to show what I mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `display:inline` for IE. And keep `display: inline-block;` for other browsers..

Comment: Thanks but I tried that. In fact am using it for IE7. But when I also add it to IE8 it makes no difference.

Comment: Trying it Caroline Elisa. will get back to you soon.

Comment: Try to give display:inline\0/; clear:left\0/; to figure tag and  display:inline\0/ to class gallery-icon. \0/ is hack for IE8 CSS

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Kishori! What I meant was that I had tried it on all the elements set as `inline-block`, but obviously not specifically on the `.gallery-item`.